# How to pipe and chain an operation that uses multiple `Eithers` and `Promises` from `fp-ts`

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, functional-programming, fp-ts

i'm new on `fp-ts`, i'm trying to create a functional-like method that:

1. Parse a bearer token
2. Check if the user is valid using the parsed token

```
import { Request } from 'express';
import { either } from 'fp-ts';
import { pipe } from 'fp-ts/lib/function';

// * Parse the token
declare const parseRawToken: (rawToken: string | undefined) => either.Either<Error, string>;

// * Interface of the validate method
type MakeIsRequestAuthenticated = (
  validateUserWithToken: (data: string) => Promise<either.Either<Error, void>>,
) => (request: Request) => Promise<either.Either<Error, void>>;
```

I want to chain these validations inside a pipe, so I tried to implement the validation by:

```
export const makeIsRequestAuthenticated: MakeIsRequestAuthenticated = validateUserWithToken => {
  // * Validate the request
  return async request => {
    return pipe(
      parseRawToken(request.header('Authorization')),
      either.chain(validateUserWithToken)
      );
  };
};
```

but it gives my the following error:

```
Argument of type '(data: string) => Promise<Either<Error, void>>' is not assignable to parameter of type '(a: string) => Either<Error, void>'.
  Type 'Promise<Either<Error, void>>' is not assignable to type 'Either<Error, void>'.ts(2345)
```

i had try replace the `Promise` by a `TaskEither` and some other solutions but none of them worked

I want to use the `chain` or may other some method to be able to execute all these operations inside the `pipe`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this can help:

- I've modified a litle the interface of the validate method to return the request, allowing another handler to take it and do whatever after validation
- I've modified the interface of validateUserWithToken to return TaskEither<Error, void> instead of promise.

```
import { Request } from 'express';
import { pipe } from 'fp-ts/lib/function';
import * as TE from "fp-ts/TaskEither";
import * as E from "fp-ts/Either";
import { assert } from 'console';

// * Parse the token (dummy implementation)
const parseRawToken = (rawToken: string | undefined) =>
    rawToken ? E.right(rawToken) : E.left(new Error("Invalid token"));

// * Interface of the validate method (changed return type to TastEither<Error, Request>)
type MakeIsRequestAuthenticated = (
    validateUserWithToken: (data: string) => TE.TaskEither<Error, void>,
) => (request: Request) => TE.TaskEither<Error, Request>;

//Actual implementation
export const makeIsRequestAuthenticated: MakeIsRequestAuthenticated =
    validateUser => (request: Request) =>
        pipe(
            request.header("Authorization"), //returns string | undefined
            parseRawToken, //returns  Either<Error, string>
            TE.fromEither, //To TaskEither
            TE.chain(validateUser), //validate token 
            TE.map(() => request) //If no errors return request
        )

//Mock request
const mockRequest = {
    header: (name: string) => "fake token",
    body: {
        userName: "MsFake",
    }
} as Request;

//Dummy implementations for tokenValidators: sucess and fail
const mockValidToken: (token: string) => TE.TaskEither<Error, void> =
    (token: string) => TE.right(void 0);
const mockInValidToken: (token: string) => TE.TaskEither<Error, void> =
    (token: string) => TE.left(new Error("Token not valid"));

//Test
const fail = makeIsRequestAuthenticated(mockInValidToken)(mockRequest);
const sucess = makeIsRequestAuthenticated(mockValidToken)(mockRequest);

sucess().then(d => assert(d._tag === "Right"));
fail().then(d => assert(d._tag === "Left"));
```

Now the method `MakeIsRequestAuthenticated` returns a `TaskEither<Error, Request>` and you can chain it with any method taking a `Request` as a parameter. From now on you may deal with taskEither instead of promises, but it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: this is exactly what I as trying to do, thanks, it was really helpful